# Is there a way to see just your audit questions on SE?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I failed an audit today (I tried to edit an answer that I was just supposed to reject), and now I can't remember what other audits I've failed.  I'm just curious if there is a way to only see the audited questions and whether you handled it "properly"?

Comment: There's not even a way to see *all* your audits. You can only see the ones that involved a non-deleted post in the list.

Comment: When I click on the Review link, and then go to, say, Suggested Edits, and then History, does that show me **any** audits, or just regular reviews?

Comment: It will show you any *passed* audits, so long as they weren't on posts which are now deleted. Note that the list also does not show you failed audits, since those don't count as a review action. Audits are also not denoted any differently than a regular review.

Comment: @animuson so to make it short, the answer is "no". :-/

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Well, technically a moderator can find them over the past 30 days, but that's a very manual task that they don't really care to do. So yeah, let's go with "no."

Comment: Turned this into a Feature Request.  I hope it's OK that I posted a separate question.

Comment: @animuson I think I saw Tim and Anna mentioning users they failed X or Y audits, so do Community Managers get a tool to see audits history? In such case I doubt they'll expose the tool publicly, as the OP here wants.