# Is there a way to view failed test reviews?

Tags: support, review, review-audits, recent-activity

In your userprofile, you can view your reviews (activity -> reviews). It is not clear whether a review was a test, or a legitimate review. I think passed tests are included (I'm not sure though), but failed reviews are not.

In order to learn from my mistakes, I would like to review failed (and passed) reviews. Is this possible?

Another reason I'd like this, I would like to see how many failed review you get between bans. I think I failed only once since my previous ban, despite numerous passed tests, and over 100 reviews. But I lack the data to prove it.

Comment: Also a dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209669/is-there-a-way-to-see-just-your-audit-questions-on-se